# convert percent to decimal out of 10

Tags: php, decimal

I have a ratings system where users can vote on posts and rate them in 10's. For example 10, 20, 30, 40 and so on up to 100.

When I get the AVG vote for example I get 95 how can I change the output to say 9.5

I know its probably really simple but I am struggling to find the answer. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Divide the result by 10? Is problem the formatting? You can use the [number_format](http://fr2.php.net/number_format) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$avgVote = round($avgVote/10, 1); // 95 -> 9.5
```

Comment: @S Korolev Worked Great, Thanks. Much appreciated